# Count occurrences of character and exclude missing

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I have a dataset like this

```
aa<-structure(c("AABB", "AABB", NA, "AABB", "AABB", "AABB", "AABB", 
            "AABB", "AABB", "AABB", "AAAA", "AAAA", NA, "AAAA", "AAAA", "AAAA", 
            "AAAA", "AAAA", "AAAA", "AAAA", "BBBB", NA, NA, NA, "AAAA", "AAAA", 
            NA, NA, NA, NA, "AAAA", NA, NA, NA, "AAAA", "BBBB", NA, NA, NA, 
            NA, "AABB", NA, NA, NA, "AABB", "AAAA", NA, NA, NA, NA, "AAAA", 
            "AAAA", "AAAA", "BBBB", "AAAA", "BBBB", "BBBB", "BBBB", "BBBB", 
            "BBBB", "AABB", "AABB", "AABB", "AAAA", "AABB", "AAAA", "AABB", 
            "AAAA", "AAAA", "AAAB", "BBBB", "BBBB", NA, "AABB", "AABB", "AABB", 
            "AABB", "AABB", "AABB", "AABB", "AAAA", "AAAA", NA, "AAAA", "AAAA", 
            "AAAA", "AAAA", "AAAA", "AAAA", "AAAA", "BBBB", "BBBB", NA, "BBBB", 
            "BBBB", "AAAA", "AAAA", "BBBB", "BBBB", "ABBB"), .Dim = c(10L, 10L))
```

I am trying to count "A" in each. I tried 2 approaches.

`str_count` of `stringr` package.

```
> apply(aa,2,str_count,"A")
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    2    4    0    4    2    4    2    0    4     0
 [2,]    2    4    1    1    1    4    2    0    4     0
 [3,]    1    1    1    1    1    4    2    1    1     1
 [4,]    2    4    1    1    1    0    4    2    4     0
 [5,]    2    4    4    4    2    4    2    2    4     0
 [6,]    2    4    4    0    4    0    4    2    4     4
 [7,]    2    4    1    1    1    0    2    2    4     4
 [8,]    2    4    1    1    1    0    4    2    4     0
 [9,]    2    4    1    1    1    0    4    2    4     0
[10,]    2    4    1    1    1    0    3    2    4     1
```

Here I get `1` for missing. but I like to have `NA`

and `regex`

```
dosage<-function(string,char){

  x<-sapply(regmatches(string, gregexpr(char, string)), length)
  return(x)
}

apply(aa,2,dosage,"A")

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    2    4    0    4    2    4    2    0    4     0
 [2,]    2    4    0    0    0    4    2    0    4     0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    4    2    0    0     0
 [4,]    2    4    0    0    0    0    4    2    4     0
 [5,]    2    4    4    4    2    4    2    2    4     0
 [6,]    2    4    4    0    4    0    4    2    4     4
 [7,]    2    4    0    0    0    0    2    2    4     4
 [8,]    2    4    0    0    0    0    4    2    4     0
 [9,]    2    4    0    0    0    0    4    2    4     0
[10,]    2    4    0    0    0    0    3    2    4     1
```

Here I get `0`, but again I like to have `NA`.

How do I do it?

Comment: you could just replace `return(x)` with `ifelse(is.na(string), NA, x)` and your `dosage` function will work as you want

Comment: @rawr yes, this worked..

Comment: your `apply` function gives me the intended output

Comment: Another option in base is `nchar(aa, keepNA=TRUE) - nchar(gsub("A", "", aa))` or `nchar(matrix(gsub("[^A]","",aa), nrow(aa), ncol(aa)), keepNA=TRUE)`

Comment: Or `matrix(attr(regexpr("A+", aa), "match.length"), nrow(aa), ncol(aa))` if your `A`s are always consecutive.

Answer (score 1):

You can just can `str_count` directly and format it as a `matrix`.

```
library(stringr)
matrix(str_count(aa, "A"), nrow=nrow(aa), ncol = ncol(aa))
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    2    4    0    4    2    4    2    0    4     0
 [2,]    2    4   NA   NA   NA    4    2    0    4     0
 [3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    4    2   NA   NA    NA
 [4,]    2    4   NA   NA   NA    0    4    2    4     0
 [5,]    2    4    4    4    2    4    2    2    4     0
 [6,]    2    4    4    0    4    0    4    2    4     4
 [7,]    2    4   NA   NA   NA    0    2    2    4     4
 [8,]    2    4   NA   NA   NA    0    4    2    4     0
 [9,]    2    4   NA   NA   NA    0    4    2    4     0
[10,]    2    4   NA   NA   NA    0    3    2    4     1
```

Comment: still giving me the output as first. Seems it's not recognizing `NA` as missing. I tried `is.na(aa)`, which gave expected TRUE/FALSE though

Comment: @Ananta This works for me. Maybe try it in a new R session. ... Actually your original `apply` code also works for me.

Comment: Interesting, the original and this solution worked in windows but not linux..